# Java StringFormat para que el formato de la cadena quede ordenado

Tags: java, string, formato

Estoy programando para que una tabla quede ordenada, los valores debajo del título de cada columna, pero me sale completamente desordenado. He programado lo siguiente:

```
 String str = String.format("%-45s || %-12s || %-10s || %-21s%n", "Nombre de Producto", "Precio", "Numero", "Precio Productos");
 String st_ = String.format("%-45s || %-12s || %-10s || %-21s%n", "------------------", "------", "------", "----------------");
 factura.append(str);
 factura.append(st_);

 String str2 = String.format("%-45s || %-12s || %-10s || %-21s%n", fv.getNombrePro(),fv.getPrecioProducto(),fv.getNumeroItems(),fv.getPrecioItems());
 factura.append(str2);
```

El resultado que devuelve esa impresión es el siguiente:

| Nombre de Producto |  | Precio |  | Numero |  | Precio Productos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tijeras podar modelo Bellota |  | 17.99 |  | 2 |  | 35.98 |
| Escoba Sputnick |  | 23.0 |  | 3 |  | 69.0 |
| Pala de Obra |  | 44.98 |  | 2 |  | 89.96 |

increible, por algun motivo aqui sale genial, pero en mi TextArea de una GUI sale descuadrado. Porque puede ser esto? Pego abajo la imagen de mi TextArea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que tu problema se debe a que el tipo de fuente del `TextArea` no es `monospace`, entoces, al no tener todas las letras el mismo ancho, se arma el revoltijo. Si ejecutas tu código imprimiéndolo en cualquier consola se verá correctamente.

Comment: Como solución, utiliza una Tabla, o bien establece la fuente del `textArea` a `Monospace`. Si es un `JTextArea` puedes intentar con `textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));`.

Comment: Como bien dice @JaimeMenéndez, me pregunto ¿por qué no utilizar mejor una tabla para mostrar los datos?

Comment: Gracias. Prefiero construir un String con StringBuilder porque aunque no lo menciono en la pregunta pero forman parte de la factura el nombre del cliente, su DNI, la fecha de la factura, el precio total con iva y sin iva, todos estos campos no sabría como incorporarlos a una tabla porque mi intención es crear una factura real donde la pueda previsualizar en un TextArea y luego guardarla en un fichero externo. Gracias por la ayuda